# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function ()?

Tags: flutter, widget

[image]

I want to call the state method in answer file.
[image]

Comment: try `final VoidCallback selectHandler`

Answer (score 1):

just replace the Function  Type To VoidCallback

`final VoidCallback selectHandler`

Answer (score 0):

in your declaration, you can change Function to either Function() or VoidCallback.